# Google Drive API change spreadsheet locale and timezone on upload

Tags: c#, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I use Google Drive API for .NET.

When I use **google service account** and upload Excel files to Google Drive with convert to drive format, locale in all created spreadsheets is 'en_US' and timezone is 'America/Los_Angeles'.

When I use **OAuth 2.0 client ID**, locale and timezone set from settings in my google account.

In Google Sheets API i also not found how to change this options.

How can i change locale and timezone with google service account?

Comment: My solution by now:
Google apps script

`function setSpreadsheetLocaleTimezone(id, locale, timezone){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    ss.setSpreadsheetLocale(locale);
    ss.setSpreadsheetTimeZone(timezone);
}`

And execute this script with Apps Script Execution API after upload Excel files.